# How to provide a minimal facebook page like on a website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am sure this has been asked before, but I can't find it.

I want a simple facebook like button on my website which makes facebook users *like* my facebook page.

I have seen it in action on the codelab of http://www.tutorialrepublic.com:

[image: facebook like]

Is this no longer possible? When I add the facebook page plugin, I always get a small profile picture included and the title of the facebook page. This is simply to invasive for my site.

*Edit: *

## Expected behavior:

1. User clicks a like button on website abc.com
2. The count of likes on that button increases by 1
3. The user is now following **the facebook page** of abc.com and will receive updates in his/her timeline when ABC publishes a facebook post

I know there has been [a change in the facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages) with a deprecation of the like-button in favour of the page plugin.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Go _test_ it. And the Like Button is not deprecated in favor of the Page plugin, the Like _Box_ is (and that is a different thing than the Like Button.)

Comment: @CBroe that explains so much!

Answer (score 0):

You want the Like button, not the Page plugin.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Comment: But that does not make you like the facebook page, does it? That makes you like the website, not the facebook page parallel to the website.

Comment: It likes what you point it to - either an external website, or a Facebook page.

Comment: Thanks, so what is the difference with the page plugin? If you hit like on a page plugin does it do something different from hitting the like button you suggest?

Comment: I mean: does the user start following the facebook page they liked?

Comment: Try it and find out …?

Comment: This should be documented somewhere shouldn't it? I have no clue how facebook works. All I can find confuses me even more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages